# How to use if, elif and else statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am a beginner to programming(only 9 days).

I recently learned if, else statements.
 But I am facing a problem when applying it.

When I use code

```
    y=input('ans>>')
    if y=='c':
        q=5
    elif y=='a'or'b'or'd':
        q=-1
    else:
        q=0
    print(q)
```

when I input c it gives me 5, when  i input a it gives me -1 but

when I input no other than a,b,c,d it still gives me -1 every time but it is suppose to give 0

how do I fix this?

Comment: What is q initialized to?

Answer (score 1):

```
y=input('ans>>')
if y=='c':
    q=5
elif y in ['a', 'b', 'd']: //similar to y=='a' or y=='b' or y=='d'
    q=-1
else:
    q=0
print(q)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `elif` condition. The order of evaluation of the `or`s is not as you expect. Python reads it as:

`((y == 'a') or 'b') or 'd')`

If `y == 'a'` is `False`, then it evaluates to `(False or 'b') or 'd'`. `False or 'b'` evaluates to `'b'`, and finally `'b' or 'd'` evaluates to `'b'`, which is not zero or `None`, so the `elif` will consider this to be `True`.

As suggested by others, either write:

`elif y == 'a' or y == 'b' or y == 'd':`

Or write:

`elif y in ['a', 'b', 'd']:`

Answer (score 1):

I may recommend you to learn about boolean type and operation with it like "or","and".
To be short - you have to operate with "and" and "or" on the logical expression of comparison:

y=='a'

y=='b'

y=='d'

All three should be the different comparison that produces True or False
AND THEN you may test logical "or" "and" with results.
'''
if y=='a' or y=='b' or y=='d':

Keep in mind that logical operations over boolean values produces the following result:

True or False is True

True and False is False

False and False is False

False or False is False

I hope this will help